# Appropriate way to use (read/write) a variable with different instances?

Tags: python

I have $100 cash to get some food.
Then, what is an appropriate/correct way to read/write a variable (`cash`) globally with different instance(`apple`, `banana`)?

```
#-- class definitions
class Wallet():
    cash=100

class Food():
    w=Wallet()
    def __init__(self,price):
        self.price=price
    def purchase(self,num):
        self.w.cash-=num*self.price

#-- instantiation
apple=Food(price=5)
banana=Food(price=10)

#-- call method
apple.purchase(num=3) #5*3=15
banana.purchase(num=4) #10*4=40
print(apple.w.cash) #100-(15+40)=45
print(banana.w.cash) #100-(15+40)=45
```

This looks correct, but I feel uncomfortable because this code overwrites `cash`, which is defined as a class variable in `Wallet` class. (Class variables should not be overwritten, from my understanding.)

Would it be better not to define `Wallet` class but to define `cash` as a global variable?
If I insist on defining `Wallet` class, how should `cash` be treated in instantiated classes?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using class attributes for what you are doing because they are shared by all instances of the class. It's also a good idea to stay away from global variables. See [Global Variables Are Bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you meant static class variables shouldn't be overwritten.
Also I'm not sure why food has a purchase method. Perhaps you can create another class such as Customer, then have Wallet be a class variable of Customer.

You can do something like:

```
class Wallet:
    def __init__(self, cash):
       self.cash = cash

    def add_cash(self, amount):
       self.cash += amount

    def subtract_cash(self, amount):
       self.cash -= amount

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, wallet):
       self.wallet = wallet

    def purchase(self, food):
       self.wallet.subtract_cash(food.value)

class Food:
    def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value
```

Comment: Thank you for the fabulous answer. very understandable.
It is a good solution to have an instance variable(from Wallet class) be the variable of another class(Customer), and in that way every customer can use(share) one single wallet (as long as sharing the same instantiated variable from Wallet class)!